# Reply by message to sender using Arduino Nano and Sim900 module

Tags: arduino, sms, sim900, replay

I use arduino Nano and Sim900 module. I want, when a message is received, Arduino to reply back `"thanks"` to the sender.
My message receive function code is:

```
void recieveSms(){
  Serial.print("\r");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");        
  delay(1000);                
  Serial.print("AT+CSCS=\"GSM\"\r");
  delay(1000);                  
  Serial.print("AT+CNMI=2,1\r");// set new message remind        
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGR=2\r"); // read message at position 2
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGD=2\r");  // delete SMS at position 2
  delay(1000);  
}
```

that works, but how I can retrieve sender number from the message?

Answer (score 1):

Its easy to use the [GSM Library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/GSM) that comes with arduino IDE.

> The GSM library is included with Arduino IDE 1.0.4 and later.

Using this libarray use [`remoteNumber()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/GSMSMSRemoteNumber)

Here is the example code on the documentation page

```
#include <GSM.h>

// PIN Number
#define PINNUMBER ""

// initialize the library instance
GSM gsmAccess; // include a 'true' parameter for debug enabled
GSM_SMS sms;

char remoteNumber[20];  // Holds the emitting number

void setup()
{
    // initialize serial communications
    Serial.begin(9600);

    Serial.println("SMS Messages Receiver");

    // connection state
    boolean notConnected = true;

    // Start GSM shield
    // If your SIM has PIN, pass it as a parameter of begin() in quotes
    while(notConnected)
    {
        if(gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER)==GSM_READY)
            notConnected = false;
        else
        {
            Serial.println("Not connected");
            delay(1000);
        }
    }

    Serial.println("GSM initialized");
    Serial.println("Waiting for messages");
}

void loop()
{
    char c;

    // If there are any SMSs available()  
    if (sms.available())
    {
        Serial.println("Message received from:");

        // Get remote number
        sms.remoteNumber(remoteNumber, 20);
        Serial.println(remoteNumber);

        // This is just an example of message disposal    
        // Messages starting with # should be discarded
        if(sms.peek()=='#')
        {
            Serial.println("Discarded SMS");
            sms.flush();
        }

        // Read message bytes and print them
        while(c=sms.read())
            Serial.print(c);

        Serial.println("\nEND OF MESSAGE");

        // delete message from modem memory
        sms.flush();
        Serial.println("MESSAGE DELETED");
    }

    delay(1000);

}
```

Comment: this solution dont work for me.by gsm library I can't send messge.why?I connected Rx of sim900 to tx of Arduino nano and tx of sim900 to rx of Arduino Nano.

Comment: I very search about this solution.I think this example only work with Arduino GSM Shield but I dont have It.I have an Sim900 module.

Comment: just connect the pins that are used for software serial to connect to your SIm900 rx tx.

Comment: thanks your help,I connect sim900 rx,tx to pin 2,3 of arduino according gsmShield lib help.but dont send message.